# Change from JS Puppeteer code to PuppeteerSharp C#

Tags: javascript, c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I have `Javascript puppeteer` code, and `PuppeteerSharp for C#`. I know that this libraries are similar, and i know their sites.

But my problem that i barely can manage this libraries, there are alot of methods for each lib, and it hard to find needed methods, even i have working example written on JS.

Please help me rewrite JS code to C#, so it would do similar things. Or at least function names, for example JS (puppeteer) method = C# (puppeteerSharp) method.

```
(async function main() {
      try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const [page] = await browser.pages();
        page.setDefaultTimeout(0);

        await page.goto('www.example.com');

        await page.waitForSelector('#search-content button.btn-icon');
        let count = 0;
        while (await page.$('#search-content button.btn-icon') !== null && count != 1) {
          const articlesForNow = (await page.$$('#search-content article')).length;
          console.log(`Articles for now: ${articlesForNow}. Getting more...`);
          count += 1;
          await Promise.all([
            page.evaluate(
              () => {
                document.querySelector('#search-content button.btn-icon').click();
              }
            ),
            page.waitForFunction(
              old => document.querySelectorAll('#search-content article').length > old, {},
              articlesForNow
            ),
          ]);
        }

        const articlesAll = (await page.$$('#search-content article')).length;
        console.log(`All articles: ${articlesAll}.`);

        fs.writeFileSync('full.html', await page.content());

        fs.writeFileSync('articles.html', await page.evaluate(
          () => document.querySelector('#search-content div.b-filter__inner').outerHTML
        ));

        fs.appendFileSync('articles.txt', await page.evaluate(
              (fr) => {
                let items = document.querySelectorAll(".product__body");
                let appartmentsData = "";

                for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                  let itemLink = items[i].querySelector(".product__link").href;
                  let itemName = items[i].querySelector(".product__link strong").innerHTML;
                  let itemPrice = items[i].querySelector(".product__value").innerHTML;

                  return appartmentsData;
                }, fr
              ));
              // rest of the code
```

That what I have so far:

```
using(var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions())) {
 var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
 await page.GoToAsync(LINK);
 await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#search-content button.btn-icon");

 while (await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#search-content button.btn-icon") != null) {
  var articlesForNow = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("#search-content article");

  Console.WriteLine("Items proceed: " + articlesForNow.Length);

  for (int i = 0; i < articlesForNow.Length; i++) {
   string itemOuterHtml = await articlesForNow[i].EvaluateFunctionAsync < string > ("e => e.outerHTML");
  }

  await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#search-content button.btn-icon").EvaluateFunctionAsync("e => e.click()");
 }
}
```

But It's infinity counting and does not stop. After element is 1275 it throws the error about my method in while loop.

```
PuppeteerSharp.WaitTaskTimeoutException: waiting for selector '#search-content button.btn-icon' failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

Answer (score 4):

We cannot convert the whole code for you but here are some pointers. You need to take one chunk of problem at a time.

## Break the while loop

Let us look into the JS code,

```
let count = 0;
while (await page.$('#search-content button.btn-icon') !== null && count != 1) {}
```

It's creating a while look, which stops if count is 1.

Now your C# Code,

```
while (await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#search-content button.btn-icon") != null)
```

It's not checking for count, this will end up in infinite while loop.

You should count the number,

```
int count = 0;
while (await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#search-content button.btn-icon") != null && count != 1){
 // other code
 count++;
}
```

This way it will stop after it finds one result.

## Learn more about Promise.all etc.

Your rest of the question is about Promise.all and few other stuff. Here are some useful links,

- [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [API Documentation for Puppeteer Sharp](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/index.html)
- [API Documentation for Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: Just checked back what happened to this question. I applaud your patience with OP, upvoted :)